# Dirichlet Problem on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Find a C-harmonic function in the unit disk with boundary values $x^3-xy$.
I know the answer is $u(x,y)=\frac{(x^3-3xy^2)}{4} + \frac{3x}{4} - xy$ but don't know how to solve it
Any hint or help is appreciated
Thanks
(C-harmonic function is a function which is harmonic in the interior of a domain and continuous the closure)

I found a solution but I couldn't understand much.
"Soluiton: Since $z^3 = (x^3$-$3xy^2$)+i($3x^2$-$y^3$) is analytic on the unit disk, its real part is harmonic there with boundary values $x^3-3xy^2$=$4x^3-3x$. Clearly xy is harmonic everywhere. Therefore the required function is $u(x,y)=\frac{(x^3-3xy^2)}{4} + \frac{3x}{4} - xy$."

I think in the solution "Poisson Kernel" is used but I can't figure out where it has been used.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. Please be more clear in your question. Define C-harmonic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to verify that your candidate function verifies the boundary values requirement (it is straightforward).
2. The real (and imaginary) part of a holomorphic function is harmonic (it is a theorem) and the sum of harmonic functions is harmonic. $xy$ is harmonic because it is the imaginary part of $z \mapsto z^2$.

Comment: Thank you I understand it now. We put $y^2=1-x^2$ then leave $x^3$ alone then add -xy which is required $u(x,y)$